# iOS IAP - Does sandbox users have purchases from live store?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, skpaymenttransaction

If a user has bought an non-consumable IAP in the live app, does this user have the IAP in the sandbox environment if he is set up as iTunesConnect user & tester? Can this user then "restore" the purchase via `restoreCompletedTransactions`? Or does he have to buy it in the sandbox environment in order to be able to restore it?

Example flow

1. User installs version `1` frrom `live` environment
2. User purchase IAP `A` from `live` environment
3. User installs testflight app version `2`
4. User wants to restore purchase `A` within `sandbox` environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Sandbox and live are two separate environments. The user has to buy it in sandbox in order to be able to restore it later.

Answer (score 0):

YES, The sandbox backend works like a real account-- once it's purchased, it's purchased (and thus you can test restore).

Comment: Well, but i mean if he bought it before the test app, in the live version before. and never bought it in the sandbox environment. can he then restore that purchase in the sandbox environment?

Comment: No, you can't because both have different environments.